# Compressing unicode strings

Tags: swift, unicode, compression, lzw

I am looking for an algorithm to compress Unicode strings in Swift. The strings I will compress will be relatively small (no more then 160 characters).

I found the LZW compression already implemented [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression#Swift). I copy pasted the code which worked well with ASCII characters but as soon as I added some Unicode characters, I got a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` while compressing, on the line `result.append(dict[w]!)` my guess is that the algorithm doesn't support unicode characters since `dict[c]` is undefined for any Unicode character `c`.

How can I tweak that algorithm in order to support Unicode characters or should I try other compression methods? If so, which ones?

**EDIT**

By changing the loop at the beginning from

```
for i in 0 ..< 256
{
    let s = String(UnicodeScalar(i))
    dict[s] = i
}
```

to

```
for i in 0 ..< 0xFFFF
{
    let s = String(UnicodeScalar(i))
    dict[s] = i
}
```

I can get the algorithm to work, although, that solution requires too much calculation time and memory.